# Enviar correo si una consulta tiene un campo vacio(NULL) c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, email

Me gustaria saber si hay alguna manera de poder validar si una consulta que tengo en SQL Server contiene campos con NULL y si es asi enviar un correo informando que hay campos en null, esto mas que nada para evitar estar ejecutando diario la consulta y revisar si contiene campos en null y por medio de un mensaje a traves de correo que se estara ejecutando diario mandar un mensaje cuando encuentre campos en null y en caso contrario que tenga un mensaje que todo esta correcto, esto lo estare trbajando en un proyecto de consola c#
Beuno espero me puedan apoyar con sus consejos para saber que puedo hacer, Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si bien el SQL te permite enviar email, no es la solución más sencilla ni recomendada.

Ya que estas trabajando con C# te recomiendo que le pongas una función al programa (ej. "MiPrograma.exe /chequearNulls") que haga la consulta chequeando por valores en null y mande los mails correspondientes de ser necesario.

Comment: Realmente no te entendi, solo para aclarar aun no tengo nada para hacer lo que mencione ya que no tengo idea de como hacerlo, es por eso que estoy pidiendo consejos para poder realizarlo gracias